# how to get user radio button selected values

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to get user selected value , below is my code.
Here are two packages with different prices names etc, shown fine, but what so ever user selected it treats as first one is selected.

PHP/HTML Code

```
<?php

$sql_pac=mysql_query("select * from package1 where status=0 order by package_id");
$i=0;
while($res_pac=mysql_fetch_array($sql_pac)){ 
 //$products=unserialize(stripslashes($res_pac['products']));
 //echo $products[$i];?>

  <tr class="RowBGStandard">
      <td>
          <input  name="package" value="<?php echo $res_pac["package_id"] ?>"
             <?php echo ($res_pac["package_id"]==2) ? 'checked' : '' ?> type="radio">
          <input type="hidden" name="package_volume" value="<?php echo $res_pac["total_bv"] ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="package_price" value="<?php echo $res_pac["total_fees"] ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="package_name" value="<?php echo $res_pac["package_name"] >">
      </td>
      <td align="right"><strong><!--710-->&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-6 control-label">
         <strong><?php echo $res_pac["package_name"] ?></strong>
      </td>
      <td align="right">
         <strong><?php echo Currency.' '.$res_pac["total_fees"] ?></strong>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="RowBGStandard">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="1" class="col-lg-6 control-label">
         <em><?php echo $res_pac["description"] ?></em>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="6" height="3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td height="1" colspan="6" bgcolor="black">
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="6" height="3">
       </td>
   </tr>

<?php $i++;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, is there more to this? when you say "it treats as first one is selected" what is "it". can you post a link or the full issue

Comment: atmd here the link http://198.12.105.99/~rhyico46/store/registration.php

Comment: exercise caution, and be vigilant when going to links like that.  @atmd et al.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
if($res_pac["package_id"] == 2){
  $selectedTwo = 1;
} else {
  $selectedTwo = 0;
}
?>

<input name="package" value="<?php echo $res_pac['package_id']; ?>" <?php echo ($selectedTwo) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> type="radio">
```

See, if that works